# CultureInfo changes based on computer settings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core

I am running a .NET 5 MVC Web Application through IIS both on my local machine and a remote server.

I have noticed a strange bug where the computer's local settings appear to affect the result of the `CultureInfo` class

In Windows 10, if I open `Settings > Time & Language > Region`, and click `Change data formats` so that my Short time is 24 hour, i.e. 13:40 vs 1:40 PM, then the result of `CultureInfo` will also change. I had always assumed that changing my computer settings should not affect .NETs built in cultures, and that they should be the same no matter what computer the code runs on, so:

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

Should return the same `CultureInfo` object no matter what computer the code is running on or what Date & Time settings the user decides to use.

I initially wondered if perhaps I was using the `CultureInfo` class wrong, so I also tried:

```
new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

But the results were the same.

Is there some way to tell the `CultureInfo` class to use the default values for the culture and not the use the settings that I currently have on my computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
```

The second parameter of the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor) (useUserOverride) means exactly that.

- true use the system settings
- false use the default culture settings